# xscreensaver - gluqlo digital clock: not installed on LUbuntu

Tags: lubuntu, xscreensaver

On a fesh LUbuntu 22.04.04 install I'm trying to get gluqlo digital clock screensaver up and running.

https://github.com/alexanderk23/gluqlo

downloaded source, compiled it as described here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtpvvATRB4s

When I open screensaver preferences GLUqlo is greyed out and the preview says 'not installed'
[image]

the compiled /usr/share/applications/screensavers/gluqlo.desktop exists and when I execute it, the application starts
[image]

I can call settings in screensaver preferences:
[image]

However there is an error when I press preview:

```
xscreensaver: <date> could not execute "qluqlo": no such file or directory

current directory is /home/user

path is /usr/libex/xscreensaver
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
...

xscreensaver signal 0 child pid terminated abnormally
```

I even copied the qluqulo.desktop file to `/usr/local/bin` without success.

When I enter a full qualified path `/home/user/gluqlo.desktop -root` in xscreensaver preferences command line, there is a different error message.

Any ideas how to fix this?